# Split() on newline AND space characters?

Tags: perl, split, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I want to `split()` a string on both newlines ***and*** space characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = "aa bb cc\ndd ee ff";
my @arr = split(/\s\n/, $str);     # Split on ' ' and '\n'
print join("\n", @arr);            # Print array, one element per line
```

Output is this:

```
aa bb cc
dd ee ff
```

But, what I want is this:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
```

So my code is splitting on the newline (good) but not the spaces.  [According to perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass), whitespace should be matched with `\s` in a character class, and I would have assumed that   is whitespace.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my code is splitting on the newline (good)

Your code is not splitting on newline; it only seems that way due to how you are printing things.  Your array contains one element, not two.  The element has a newline in the middle of it, and you are simply printing `aa bb cc\ndd ee ff`.

`\s\n` means: any whitespace followed by newline, where [whitespace](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Whitespace) actually includes `\n`.

Change:

```
my @arr = split(/\s\n/, $str);
```

to:

```
my @arr = split(/\s/, $str);
```

Using [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) makes it clear that the array now has 6 elements:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper; 

my $str = "aa bb cc\ndd ee ff";
my @arr = split(/\s/, $str);
print Dumper(\@arr);
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'aa',
          'bb',
          'cc',
          'dd',
          'ee',
          'ff'
        ];
```

---

The above code works on the input string you provided.  It is also common to   split on multiple consecutive whitespaces using:

```
my @arr = split(/\s+/, $str);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are splitting on a whitespace character followed by a line feed. To split when either one is encountered, there's

```perl
split /[\s\n]/, $str
```

But `\s` includes `\n`, so this can be simplified.

```perl
split /\s/, $str
```

But what if you have two spaces in a row? You could split when a sequence of whitespace is encountered.

```perl
split /\s+/, $str
```

There's a special input you can provide which does the same thing except it ignores leading whitespace.

```perl
split ' ', $str
```

So,

```perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my $str = "aa bb cc\ndd ee ff";
my @arr = split ' ', $str;
say for @arr;
```

Comment: `split ' ', $arr` is definitely the most elegant choice, but `split /[\s\n]+/, $arr` may be a little more clear for us novices.

Comment: @TomWilliams Only in the few seconds before you learn what `' '` means, which you can read in `perldoc split`. Also, it does propagate a falsehood: that `\s` does not contain `\n`. Nothing good can come of that.

Comment: @TomWilliams, I must disagree. `[\s\n]` is an awful way to write `\s`. It implies that `\s` doesn't match `\n`, which is false, confusing and misleading. /// Do you think that `\s` matches only the space character? That is not correct. As the answer says, it matches any of the 25 whitespace characters. This includes horizontal whitespace characters (`\h`, 18) and vertical whitespace characters (`\v`, 7). This latter includes the line feed, which is also matched by `\n`.

Comment: @TomWilliams Furthermore, `split ' '` is not equivalent to `split /\s+/` as my answer explains, so one can't simply use `split /\s+/` (or `split /[\s\n]+/`) instead as you suggest. /// And you better learn `split ' '` really fast. `' '` is the default for the first argument, leading to constructs such as `while (<>) { my @fields = split; ... }`. It's also the operation performed by `qw`. `qw( ... )` is equivalent to `split ' ', q( ... )`. These are both quite common, so pretending it doesn't exist would be a disservice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question comes from an incorrect analysis of the outcome of your code. You think you have split on newline, when you have not actually split anything at all and are in fact just printing a newline.

If you want to avoid this mistake in the future, and know exactly what your variables contain, you can use the core module [`Data::Dumper`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper):

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "aa bb cc\ndd ee ff";
my @arr = split(/\s\n/, $str);     # split on whitespace followed by newline
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;          # show exactly what is printed
print Dumper \@arr;                # using Data::Dumper
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          "aa bb cc\ndd ee ff"
        ];
```

As you would easily be able to tell, you are not printing an array at all, just a single scalar value (inside an array, because you put it there). [`Data::Dumper`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) is an excellent tool for debugging your data, and a valuable tool for you to learn.